# setting user edit permissions

Tags: users

In each user's profile there's a user reference field called "other editors." For all the users selected in that field, they should be allowed to edit that user's profile.

My first thought was that there'd be some kind of user access hook which would let me allow/deny users based on some criteria, but the only thing I can find is `hook_node_access()`, which doesn't get called when viewing a user profile. Is there a hook I'm missing, or do I need to look elsewhere?

Comment: How are you creating user profile? Definitely you are not using Content Profile. hook_node_access is used to restrict access on nodes not on user profile.

Comment: i'm just modifying the user entity to add custom fields to the user profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, there isn't a module that allows to the users listed in a user reference field to edit the user account where the field is contained.
You should write your own module.

The easier step is to alter the access callback for the user edit form, and use a function that checks the value of that field, comparing it with the value of the user currently logged in.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['user/%user/edit'])) {
      $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_user_edit_access';
  }
}

function mymodule_user_edit_access($account) {
  // The argument is the user object for the user profile being edited.
}
```

The default access callback is `user_edit_access()` which should be always called to verify that the currently logged in user has still the permission to edit the user profile, even if the user is not listed in the user reference field; users with the permission to administer users should always be allowed to edit a user account.

Comment: perfect. didn't even think of messing with the menu. thanks!